# Passing props to children not working In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This should be super simple for some of you.  I have a super simple app that I am making to teach myself the glory that is React and reactDom.  Currently, I am pulling from an API (which actually works!), however, I am unable to see any data when rendering to the screen.  Literally just two components.  I am sure that I am using props or state wrong here, I just don't know where.  It's possible that my map function is the problem as well.

Here is the code:

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios'
import { Table } from './Table'

export class DataList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        articles: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/portblog/')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                articles: res.data
            })
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(

            <div>

            <Table id={this.state.articles.id} articles={this.state.articles} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default DataList
```

And the child:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import key from "weak-key";



export const Table = (props) => (

  <div>
  <h1>Welcome to the Article List Page Home</h1>
    <li>{props.articles.map((article) => {
      {article.titles}
    })}</li>
  </div>

  );

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call is not returning anything. You need to do something like:

```
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to the Article List Page Home</h1>
  {props.articles.map(article => 
    <li>{article.titles}</li>
  )}
</div>
```

I'm not exactly sure what your desired output is, but generally you map over data to generate a set of dom elements.

Comment: Damn that was a quick fix!  Thank you kind sir!  So quick I still can't hit as answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
<li>{props.articles.map((article) => {
  {article.titles}
})}</li>
```

JSX expressions cannot be used in any arbitrary place. `props.articles.map(...)` is already an expression, so creating a new one wouldn't make sense.

`{article.titles}` inside a function creates a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) that does nothing. Nothing is returned from `map` callback, the array isn't mapped to anything.

Depending on what should resulting layout look like, it should be either

```
<li>{props.articles.map((article) => article.titles)}</li>
```

output titles within single `<li>` tag, or

```
{props.articles.map((article) => <li>{article.titles}</li>)}
```

to output a list of `<li>` tags.

ESLint [`array-callback-return`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) rule can be used to prevent the problem with callback return value.

Comment: I appreciate the help kind sir!

Comment: You're welcome. I added a link to ESLint to address this issue.

Comment: I have forgotten more than once that map requires a callback.  I don't know how this keeps happening.  Hopefully this will be the last time.  Also, yeah, I totally screwed up the <li> tag.  Obviously didn't want all articles listed in one spot.  Thank you again for helping an ID10T like me.

Comment: Sure, no problem.